# Php curl showing empty string after data

Tags: php, html, curl

Ive got this little snippet that I use to get data about what players are online in my server. The data displays correctly, I just have 1 extra empty row being echoed.

```
   <?php
$id = ***; //service ID
$api_key = '***'; //CBSM API key   
$act = 5; //action #5 indicates retrieval of online players
$response = null;

$ch = curl_init('https://api.envul.com/?s='.$id.'&api='.$api_key.'&act='.$act);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if($response !== false) {
$response_data = explode("<hr>", $response); //process the data
foreach($response_data as $player_data)
{ // listing of players
     $player_data = explode("{#!}", $player_data); //process the data
     echo 'Username: '.$player_data[0].'<br>';
} //end listing of players
} else {
echo 'Error '.curl_error($ch);; 
}
?>
```

Ive looked at countless posts on here and other sites about this issue with both `curl`, and `file_get_contents`.

Both methods return an empty string with and without actual data to display.

Comment: just run the url from browser directly with all required parameters and check what u r getting.

Comment: Very odd.. When doing that I get no empty string.

Comment: you r getting required things??

Comment: Yes, im getting the data correctly without an extra empty row. So where is the error in my code adding an extra empty row?

Comment: try with `stream_get_contents()` once.

Comment: Is it because you're echoing a line break after the record?  So it's creating a line break after the last row is echoed?

Comment: No, Ive removed the linebreak and still same result.

Comment: Ive been going nuts for a day trying to figure this out. Such a simple issue yet so hard to figure out. Ive tried all as stated in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/3oek8j/php_file_get_contents_returning_empty_string/) thread as well as all other answers posted on SO that are similar to my issue. To no avail however.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply, but I tried with the stream_get_contents and it is still returning an empty user.  NOTE: I am only returned an empty user if there are other players in the server, when the server is empty and I get "no players online" there is no empty user string being thrown at me. Could this be an api issue?